# Check if sub directories are present in ./work when it is created inside makefile?

Tags: makefile

In my makefile, I want to check if sub directories are present in a given folder.
This is how I am doing it now..

```
setup:
      mkdir -p ./work

DIR=$(shell find ./work -maxdepth 0 -type d -print)
check:
     if [-z $(DIR) ]; then \
       echo "null" ; \
     else  \
       echo "present" ; \
     fi;
```

I cannot create the ./work outside the makefile. So the problem is that since ./work is created inside the makefile, it gives me an  error/warning that ./work is not present before actually executing the script.

Is there a way to check if sub directories are present in ./work when it is created inside makefile?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, which also is supportive of the make principle to build/create only things that your target is depending on, are [*order-only*](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types) prerequisites. Now that you have heard this term *order-only* I want you from now on to mentally replace it with the much better fitting term "existence-only" (which is completely unofficial because I made it up) to gain an easier understanding. *order-only* prerequisites are written in the prerequisite list to the right side of a `|` pipe symbol and their meaning is: the target of this rule depends on the existence of this prerequisite but not on its timestamp. This is exactly what we want from a rule that needs to place something inside of a directory: if the directory exists, then we don't care about its date (mainly because in Unix directories get a new timestamp when a new file is created there) and we carry on with the rest of the targets dependencies. If however the directory doesn't exist, execute its rule first, which hopefully creates the directory:

```
.PHONY: all
all: foo 
    @cat subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir/foo.txt

subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir/foo.txt: | subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir
    @echo This is file foo.txt > subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir/foo.txt

subdir:
    mkdir subdir

subdir/subsubdir: | subdir
    mkdir subdir/subsubdir

subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir: | subdir/subsubdir
    mkdir subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir
```

Comment: Hi Vroomfondel, Thank you very much. Now I know about order-only per-requisites and this is very useful.

Comment: However in my case , even if I make 'setup' as an order only per-requisite, the shell command is executed even before the order only ore-requisite sending the error that 'find command couldn't find ./work and then it will create the same.

Comment: Strange, for me it works. Do you really use the `DIR = ` assignment which will be expanded later, or do you use `DIR := `? BTW you should rename the `check`target to `work`, as make always executes this rule if the target isn't present in the filesystem.